# how to render a static folder in express js inside multipal routers ("admin/addproducts/hello")

Tags: node.js, express

i am trying to add a static folder having CSS inside a multiple routers eg. (admin/products/viewproducts) but i am not being to load the css while render the view 
my code at app.js to view public files

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public")));
```

the get request for index.ejs

```
router.get("/admin/showProducts", (req, res, next) => {
res.render("index");});
```

Comment: To debug `express.static()` issues, we need to know three things.  1) Show the exact directory hierarchy where the static files are located and how that is positioned relative to the `__dirname` you're running `express.static()` from, 2) Which exact file you're having trouble with and 3) What the CSS URLs in your web page look like for that file.  The most likely problem is that your CSS URLs don't start with `/` so they're being interpreted relative to the page URL which is not what you want, but that's just a guess until we know those 3 things above.

Comment: the css is being loaded untill i use "routers.get("/admin",(req,res,next)=>{res.render("index")})"

Comment: but the css will not work when i add "routers.get("/admin/showProducts",(req,res,next)=>{res.render("index")})"

Comment: I asked you for three pieces of information in order to help.  You have not supplied any of that information.  Can't help without that information.

Comment: 1) ans "./public"  2) "./mypp/routes/usersInfo/admin/ShowProducts"   3) "localhost:3000/admin/showProducts".

Comment: For #2, I want the full path name to the CSS file on your hard drive that you are having trouble with.  For #3, I want the actual raw HTML tag from your HTML source that contains the link to the CSS file that is having problems.  For #3, I need to know exactly what the browser sees in your HTML when it goes to fetch that CSS file.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do like this:

```
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: false
}));

app.use('/', express.static('/public/css'));
app.use('/admin/showProducts', express.static('/public/css/admin/showProducts'));
```

Comment: "/admin/showProducts" in not a static file or folder its the name of my router